# CentOS desktop startx no screen found on VPS

Tags: desktop, gnome

I installed Gnome/KDE/XFCE,... on CentOS 7 on a VPS

```
yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"
```

or

```
yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
yum groupinstall "Xfce"
```

But when I run `startx` I get the following result for all desktops

```
xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.25989 does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.20.1
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System:  3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
Current Operating System: Linux centos7.cs1cloud.internal 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 14 21:24:32 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=dadd7363-eae7-4b4b-85a2-ed94705b1bed ro nomodeset crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Build Date: 14 March 2019  10:37:36AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.1-5.3.el7_6
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu May 30 08:54:16 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Appreciate for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with loading display driver, So it is need to create a new configuration file and change the display driver:
You can check the current VGA using following command:

```
lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D
```

Now edit the driver:

```
cd /root
X -configure
nano /root/xorg.conf.new
```

Change:

```
Driver      "modesetting"
```

To:

```
Driver      "dummy"
```

Save and run:

```
X -config /root/xorg.conf.new &
```